# Calculate time difference in the sql cause

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table has three columns. They are id, time1, and time2. DB is postgresql 9.1.

Now I want to get the id, which match the condition of `time2 - time1 < 72hrs`.

How can I write the sql in the where cause? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And by "time" you mean `timestamp`, I assume ..

```
SELECT id
FROM   tbl
WHERE  time2 - time1 < interval '72h';
```

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql times can be subtracted to produce an interval.  You can compare that to an interval in hours. Here's the documentation http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM theTable
WHERE time2 - time1 < interval '72 hours';
```

will return all rows where the difference between the two timestamps is less then 72 hours.

Comment: Except that it doesn't since you got the `>` operator backwards.